# How To Fetch A Single Value From MySQLi Fetch Array In PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to fetch a single value of $row_img['image_name'] from an array $row_img.
$images[] stores all the values. I want to print $images[1].

```
//The Code

while($row_img = mysqli_fetch_array($result_img)){ 
$images[] = $row_img['image_name']; 

} 
 print($images[1]);
```

Here are the array values:

```
$images[0] => 1431731493bg-2 - Copy.jpg
$images[1] => testing.jpg
$images[2] => housing.jpg
```

The error which is shown:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: images in C:\wamp\www\rightenter\property.php on line 96
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  304616  {main}( )   ..\property.php:0
```

Comment: Post your array values, and your attempts too

Comment: You need to initialize your array `$images = array();` before the while loop. And/or your code isn't populating the `$images` array, use `print_r($images);` after the while loop to check that it's been populated.

Comment: The print_r($images); just give " Array ( ) " as output.